# query multiple conditions using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How do I query multiple conditions, and when one of the conditions is empty is ignored, and the other conditions apply ?

**this Is My Code**

```
            var SalesAsInt = Convert.ToInt32(txtSalesNo.Text);
            var YearAsInt = Convert.ToInt32(cbxYear.Text);
            var MonthAsInt = Convert.ToInt32(cbxMonth.Text);
            var DayaAsInt = Convert.ToInt32(cbxDay.Text);
            using (var dbcontext = new Database.SalesEntities())
            {
                BindingSource VSalesIncome = new BindingSource();
                VSalesIncome.DataSource = dbcontext
                                 .VSalesIncomes
                                 .Where(u => u.SalesCode  == SalesAsInt )
                                 .Where(u => u.YearIncome == YearAsInt)
                                 .Where(u => u.MonthIncome == MonthAsInt)
                                 .Where(u => u.DayIncome == DayaAsInt)
                                 .ToList();

                dgvadministration.DataSource = VSalesIncome;
            }
```

**Error When any text box is Empty**

```
System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following two changes :

```
int? SalesAsInt = (txtSalesNo.Text == string.Empty) ? null : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(txtSalesNo.Text);

.Where(u => (SalesAsInt == null) ? true : u.SalesCode  == SalesAsInt )
```

Comment: To expand on this answer. The first change covers the case of the Exception when you cannot convert from a value that is invalid. Second change is a simple boolean logic - each "Where" condition is checked against an item in your database and the item is returned if the Where returns true, so you want this to happen if the given filter matches or if the filter is empty.

Comment: this line 
int? SalesAsInt = (txtSalesNo.Text == string.Empty) ? null :Convert.ToInt32(txtSalesNo.Text);

Error
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0173 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'int' Sales Saya World C:\Users\20101\Desktop\Sales Saya World\Sales Saya World\Report\frmSalesIncome.cs 39 Active

Comment: Convert.Toint32 returns a int so you need a cast : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(txtSalesNo.Text)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `Where` methods in `if` statements

```
var query = VSalesIncome.DataSource = dbcontext.VSalesIncomes
if (SalesAsInt > 0)
    query = query.Where(u => u.SalesCode  == SalesAsInt)
// repeat as needed
VSalesIncome.DataSource = query.ToList()
```